# Django ChoiceField Returns Select a Valid Choice Error in Class Based View

Tags: python, django, forms

I am pulling my hair out over this...all other SO questions relate to `ModelChoiceField` and that is not what I need.

So I have a lookup table in a SQL database that contains an ID and a keyword. This table is NOT UNIQUE meaning keywords can be duplicated but IDs are still unique. This means I cannot use `ModelChoiceField` since I want to populate it with unique keywords and using it will result in returning duplicated keywords.

Thus, I tried using `ChoiceField` and instantiating the choices in my class form as so:

```
def unique_values():
    return keyword.objects.order_by('keyword').values_list('keyword', 
        'keyword').distinct()

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    keywords = forms.ChoiceField(choices=unique_values, 
        widget=Select2MultipleWidget)
```

This works in populating the dropdown list form in my Class Based view. but when I select and submit the form, I get the result: `Select a valid choice. ['(*INSERT KEYWORD NAME*)'] is not one of the available choices.`. How do I get around this?

EDIT:
Sytech's answer in the comments solved this.

Comment: You can use a `ModelChoiceField` here. Just use an appropriate queryset that returns the unique keyword objects.

Comment: @sytech My understanding is that unique objects are only unique if all rows are unique. In my case - if I have 'Cat' as a keyword and it's duplicated for IDs 1 and 2, a distinct query will still return both cats. Also, in any case, I don't want to use a Model field since I don't want objects returned in the POST response. I am only using this to find IDs based off keywords selected. I am wondering if using a functional based view is better given the uniqueness of my table...

Comment: For example, you can do `keyword.objects.values('keyword').distinct()` if using postgres, you can do `keyword.objects.distinct('keyword')`. By default the *value* used in the form submission will be the primary key of the model (e.g. the ID). You can change this with the `to_field_value` keyword argument. So I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't want the objects returned in the `POST`.

Comment: @sytech argh, I guess my lack of understanding of django queries was the culprit. using distinct(keyword) works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ModelChoiceField` here no problem. Just use an appropriate queryset that returns the unique keyword objects.

For example, you can use the following queryset when using postgres

```
...
keyword = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=keyword.objects.distinct('keyword'))
...
```